# Sharing a Timer/Variable between Windows

Tags: vb.net, winforms, timer, stopwatch

I have a timer running like a scoreboard countdown timer. Is there a way that I can display that same timer into two windows forms (winforms) without resorting to properties?

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to use properties?

Comment: I kind of figured it would be awkward doing something like this with the use of properties. If it's the only way then I'm for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing a reference to the timer in the constructor of your other forms and add your own tick event handler:

```
Public Class Form2

  Public Sub New(ByVal mainTimer As Timer)
    InitializeComponent()
    AddHandler mainTimer.Tick, AddressOf mainTimer_Tick
  End Sub

  Private Sub mainTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    '// do something
  End Sub

End Class
```